# Torch: Concatenating tensors of different dimensions

Tags: lua, size, concatenation, torch, tensor

I have a `x_at_i = torch.Tensor(1,i)` that grows at every iteration where i = 0 to n. I would like to concatenate all tensors of different sizes into a matrix and fill the remaining cells with zeroes. What is the most idiomatic way to this. For example:

```
x_at_1 = 1
x_at_2 = 1 2
x_at_3 = 1 2 3
x_at_4 = 1 2 3 4
X = torch.cat(x_at_1, x_at_2, x_at_3, x_at_4)
X = [ 1 0 0 0
      1 2 0 0
      1 2 3 0
      1 2 3 4 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know `n` and assuming you have access to your `x_at_i` easily at each iteration I would try something like

```
X = torch.Tensor(n, n):zero()
for i = 1, n do
    X[i]:narrow(1, 1, i):copy(x_at[i])
end
```